# Slick headOption doing nothing

Tags: slick, play-slick

I have a simple MySQL db with a single row in the REG_PERIODS table. When I run this query I get the row back.

```
val getRegPeriodAction = regPeriods.sortBy(_.endDate).result.head.map { regPeriod ⇒
  Logger.debug(s"regPeriod = ${regPeriod}")

  regPeriod
}
```

However, when I run this query, I get nothing, in fact the debug message isn't even being reached!

```
val getRegPeriodAction = regPeriods.sortBy(_.endDate).result.headOption.map { regPeriodOption ⇒
  Logger.debug(s"regPeriodOption = ${regPeriodOption}")

  regPeriodOption match {
    case Some(regPeriod) ⇒ regPeriod
  }
}
```

I'm using play-slick 1.0.0. Am I misunderstanding something here? Should I receive a Some(regPeriod) when using headOption?

***EDIT***

I've tried running the the `headOption` query in `db.run( ... )` and sending the result to another function, like so:

```
def handleResult(opt: Option[RegistrationPeriod]) {
  Logger.debug(s"received $opt")
}

for {
  r <- db.run( regPeriods.sortBy(_.endDate.desc).result.headOption )
  _ <- handleResult( r )
} ...
```

The odd thing is that handleResult is never called! As soon as I change the code to call `head` instead of `headOption` everything works as expected.

Comment: Did you solve your problem already? Are you sure `result.headOption` returns a nonempty `Option`? `handleResult()` will be called only, if `Option` has a value.

Comment: Doh! Of course, it's returning `None` and because handleResult is in a for comprehension it's not being called! I need to do a check on the value of `r` before handling result.

Answer (score 4):

`.result` does not execute your query on a database. It creates an action which must be passed to `db.run()` or `db.stream()` in order to execute it:

```
val action = regPeriods.sortBy(_.endDate).result.headOption
val result: Future[Option[RegPeriod]] = db.run(action)

// accessing your data
result.map(r => r....)  // r is of type Option[RegPeriod]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, unfortunately that's not what's causing the problem. See my edit